# Get Group details from Facebook using Appcelerator

Tags: facebook, appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app using Appcelerator. In this app I need to get information from a Facebook Group.

Using the URL directly works fine. I get a complete data set of all groups docs.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/2389876494501676/docs?access_token=TOKEN HERE
```

But using the Appcelerator Facebook module just returns an empty data set.

```
Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('2389876494501676/docs', {}, 'GET', function(e) {

 Ti.API.info(e);

});
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you passing token via your function. That might be the problem

Comment: Isn´t that done automatically by the module? How can I pass it along?

Comment: I'm afraid i do not know that. But from my experience with php sdk and js sdk, you have to pass it as 'access_token' => token).

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the token is handle by the module already.

Try Ti.API.info(e.result) you should be able to see the result.